# Swift Date.now: Confused by missing parenthesis

Tags: swift

Can someone explain this syntax in an easy way?

```
let dateNow = Date.now
print(dateNow) // 2023-03-05 10:39:15 +0000
```

The documentation says:

```
static var now: Date { get }
```

**What goes on here?** Why isn't it `Date.now()`?

Comment: Because that's a computed *property*. It's marked as `var`, not `func`. So it's not a function, even though it behaves like one. That's just a thing that Swift offers.

Comment: @JanBrinker If you want: Turn your comment to an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @Sweeper Well, if he asked about it, then he doesn't know. Just because you're in a bad mood doesn't mean you have to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a computed *property*. It's marked as `var`, not `func`. So it's not a function, even though it behaves like one. That's just a thing that Swift offers.

Link to the Swift docs for a more detailed explanation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Computed-Properties